# How to add vuex action with bool return?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Im trying to add a simple common action in vuex that returns a bool,but it looks like it doesn't return what I need.

My child component call:

```
<ArrowDownIcon
    class="campaigns-grid__header-direction"
    v-if="isOrderedBy(column.id)"
    class="{'campaigns-grid__header-direction--asc': order.isDescending}"
/>
```

My imports and vuex call on root component:

```
import { createNamespacedHelpers } from 'vuex'
const { mapActions } = createNamespacedHelpers('campaigns')
    
export default {
    
    methods: {
        ...mapActions(['isOrderedBy', 'orderBy'])
    }
}
```

My vuex module ('campaigns'):

```
export default {
    namespaced: true,

    actions: {
        isOrderedBy (column) {
            if (column === 'test') {
                return true
            }

            return false
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: From where you are calling the action?

Comment: actions are not meant for this...you can try using getters

Comment: Check this link::   https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#property-style-access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as this might possibly work, You shouldn't use Vuex Actions to return Boolean values since Vuex actions return promises. The ideal process of working with vuex is:

```
-> dispatch Action -> Action makes Network calls -> Actions Commits Data to State -> Getters Pull data from State
```

To Solve this issue use Mixins, Since you're trying to make the `isOrderedBy(..)` function available application wide, and you also want it to return a boolean value depending on the provided argument.

Create a mixin folder if you don't already have one, and add an `orderMixin.js` file: the file should contain the `isOrderedBy()` function as a method.

```js
export const orderMixin = {
  methods: {
    isOrderedBy(column) {
      return column === 'test'
    }
  } 
}
```

Then within your component import the mixin and use it.

```html
<template>
...
<ArrowDownIcon
    class="campaigns-grid__header-direction"
    v-if="isOrderedBy(column.id)"
    class="{'campaigns-grid__header-direction--asc': order.isDescending}"
/>
...
</template>

<script>
import { orderMixin } from 'path-to-mixins/orderMixin'

export default {
  mixins: [orderMixin],
  ...
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In [vuex](/questions/tagged/vuex) action returns [promise](/questions/tagged/promise).

So if you want to get return value from the action you can do like

```
if (await isOrderedBy()) {
   console.log('isOrderBy returns true')
} else {
   console.log('isOrderBy returns false')
}
```